# org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "application:json;charset=utf8": does not contain '/'

Tags: java, resttemplate

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    List<MediaType> mediaTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
    mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    //mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.ALL);
    headers.setAccept(mediaTypeList);

    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, "Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH,"178");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.REFERER,"http://www.7dingdong.com/");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN,"http://www.7dingdong.com");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONNECTION,"keep-alive");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.HOST, "7ddapi.7dingdong.com");
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("",headers);
    StringBuffer paramsURL = new StringBuffer(goLoginUrl);
    paramsURL.append("?token=" +  token)
            .append("&t="+ t)
            .append("&device="+ device)
            .append("&user_name="+ user_name)
            .append("&password="+ password)
            .append("&company="+ company)
            .append("&api="+ api);


    ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            paramsURL.toString(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity,
            Object.class);
 /*
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(goLoginUrl,httpEntity,String.class);
 */
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "application:json;charset=utf8": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:534)
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:932)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:995)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
    at Login.goLogin(Login.java:268)
    at Login.main(Login.java:293)
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "application:json;charset=utf8": does not contain '/'
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:197)
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:531)
    ... 10 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54273', transport: 'socket'
```

---

How should I solve this problem？Who can help me?

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to receive the proper responses. Please check the documentation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). People will be very glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

From the error you can understand that mime type is wrong `application:json;charset=utf8`

It should be `application/json;charset=utf8`

You should use `APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` instead of `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`:

```
mediaTypeList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
```

Comment: yes，The remote interface returned "application:json;charset=utf8" instead of "application/json;charset=utf8". I don't know why,  and I ignored it with "ignoreContentType".  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` as the media type for application json `application/json`

```java
MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```